# How to determine which Java elasticsearch run through brew services

Tags: java, elasticsearch, homebrew

Elasticsearch indicates that it finds the JDK via the $JAVA_HOME environment variable.

If I have elasticsearch started through `brew services start`, how can I confirm which JDK elasticsearch is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just list processes with `ps -x`.

From `man ps`:

> **-x**        When displaying processes matched by other options, include processes which do not have a controlling terminal.

You can then select the column with the command used to launch the process:

```
ps -x | grep elasticsearch | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

You obtain then:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```